# ScrollView doesn't work with imageviews

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I want to display 2 ImageView in my scrollview like [this](http://www.noelshack.com/2013-46-1384704331-list.png), but it doesn't work.

```
<ScrollView   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@android:color/background_dark" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">





<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If i don't use android:fillViewport="true" , i see the 2 image but they are resized. If i use, size is correct but i can't get down to the second image. Why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get Screen width and height programmatically and then set the Width and height of ImageView respectively. Here is the code :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
try { 
display.getRealSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
} catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {//to deal with API 8
int height = display.getHeight();
int width = display.getWidth();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see both the images as per their sizes, you should use

```
<ImageView
...
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
.../>
```

instead of

```
<ImageView
...
android:layout_height="match_content"
.../>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try . But it doesn't work . I want each image occupies the entire screen and if I use wrap_content, i see the 2 images immediatly ( they are resized )

Comment: You can't view two images simultaneously unless one of the images is having some sort of transparency. Android lays out the views as found in the xml and if you put two images with match_parent as width and height, you will see the image added last. Do you want to divide the screen into two parts?

Comment: I add an image to explain what i want : http://www.noelshack.com/2013-46-1384704331-list.png

Comment: Do you want to try [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager)?

Comment: I will try. But i find it is easier with ScrollView, can do that with ScrollView and XML ?

Comment: Because i have already ViewPager activity ( horizontal swipe view ) and my ScrollView is on a fragment from this ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you have the image resources in the wrong folder? try removing the "fillViewport" and move the images on a lower dpi folder (from hdpi to mdpi or from mdpi to ldpi) this will change the "dp" (density-independent pixels) of the image, making them bigger on every screen.

Also, why both images have a width and height of "match_parent" ? wouldn't that make them both occupy the entire LinearLayout ?

Comment: Images are downloaded from the web, so i can't move them on a lower dpi folder.